# Want to connect two sql server of different locations through Static IP

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-replication

I have two machines . one is location A machine & another is at location B machine.

At location A I have SQL server 2008 installed with management studio & at location B also i have SQL server 2008 installed with Management studio.

Now I need to connect my location B SQL database to Location A . So that the whenever B database change A data will also change . This activity i want to perform through static IP .

Can anyone please help with how to do this . In a simple steps .

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for replication. That's a big topic.

Comment: Yes.. Can you able to help me out ..Plzz

Comment: Big topic means there is no simple answer. It requires at least an entire magazine article to describe the different replication types and how to set them up in a demo environment. You *do* need to read the [SQL Server Replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) chapter in Technet to understand what you are doing and what you need.

Comment: Why do you want replication anyway? Perhaps another solution is more suitable, eg. database mirroring for high availability